# What is the ctypes CDLL default path?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm trying to work with a library that is compiled to `/usr/local/lib/libName.so` but while running the python script that needs this file for:

```
from ctypes import CDLL
[...]
__lib = CDLL('libName.so')
```

I get:

`OSError: libName.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So i would like to know where i need to copy the .so file so that this CDLL call works properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), uses [[Man7]: DLOPEN(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) in order to load libraries, which delegates the loading (and implicitly finding) task to the *Nix* loader.

The paths to search for *.so*s is very well explained in [[Man7]: LD.SO(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). Here's what it states about default ones:

> - In the default path */lib*, and then */usr/lib*. (On some 64-bit architectures, the default paths for 64-bit shared objects are */lib64*, and then */usr/lib64*.)

Ways (most common) to solve your problem:

1. Pass the full path to *CDLL*:

   ```py
   __lib = CDLL("/usr/local/lib/libName.so")
   ```
2. Tell the loader to also search */usr/local/lib* for *.so*s, by adding it to *${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}* *env var* for the *Python* process that wants to load it:

   - ```bash
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
     # ...
     python
     ```
   - ```bash
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib python
     ```
3. Copy the *.so* in one of the default search paths (although I wouldn't recommend it, but if you must, copy it in */usr/lib* instead of */lib* (although on some *OS*es they could be *symlink*ed))

Might also worth reading [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: Can it be done from Python? Set the environment variable via `os.environ`? Seems like it can't.

Comment: @TomaszGandor: The loader does it before actually starting the process, so simply changing it via `os.environ`. I'm not aware of a way doing it at *OS* level (but this doesn't mean that there isn't one), so from *Python* you could do it starting another process (but this would only be a workaround).

Comment: Good idea! I would have to restart myself in a changed environment. Preferably before any serious work was started. Although it smells to me like "UAC elevated self restarting under Windows", but I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: @CristiFati: You could do it from Python relatively easily with a shebang; just a few lines. I'll expand on this if anyone should find it helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the library to /usr/local/lib: Copy the libName.so file directly to the /usr/local/lib directory using the following command:
sudo cp /path/to/libName.so /usr/local/lib/

Update the library cache: After copying the library, you may need to update the system's library cache to reflect the changes. You can do this by running:
sudo ldconfig

Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH (if necessary): If the library is not being found even after copying it to /usr/local/lib, you can try setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the directory where the library is located. For example:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/directory/containing/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Replace "/path/to/directory/containing/lib" with the actual path to the directory containing libName.so.

Once you've taken these steps, try running your Python script again. It should now be able to locate and load the shared library properly. If you continue to encounter issues, double-check the file permissions and ensure that the library file is not corrupted.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?